# Accessing Google Cloud Endpoints from php - 403 forbidden

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to access a python based Google Cloud Endpoints API from a php-Server, without using the php client library (simply making a POST-request, as I don't need any authorization). This worked fine for a few week, but now it doesn't work anymore, in the Server logs I get the following Error:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><meta charset=utf-8><meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width"><title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title><style>*{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png) no-repeat}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:55px;width:150px}</style><a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a><p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins><p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/_ah/spi/API.get_token</code> from this server.  (Client IP address: ****:****:*:***::**)<br><br>
We're sorry, but this service is not available in your country.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I think the Server got blocked somehow, as requests from a JS-Client still work. Any ideas, how I could reactivate the access? I would prefer, not to use the APIs Client Library for PHP.

regards,

Simon

Comment: Are you able to share the IP address? If you cannot can you create a PIT thread so I can get the information privately. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Comment: The IP address is 2a00:1128:0:148::70

Comment: Odd that's a Switzerland IP. I will need some more information, can you create a Groups thread so I can get some private information from you? Copy paste the above and I will look for the thread. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine

Comment: heres the link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/gnYrryGr_eE